# Output from two tables that has two same name columns

Tags: php, mysqli

I do have a MySQL script that put together two tables using INNER JOIN. Both tables, have a field called ID.
I do need to output with PHP, both ID fields. How do I do this?

This is my script:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id,
               a.route_id,                 
               a.requester,
               a.reservation,
               a.reservation_date,
               a.reservation_by, 
               a.telephone, 
               a.email, 
               a.firstname, 
               a.lastname, 
               a.qty_pax, 
               a.date_trip,
               a.time_trip, 
               a.trip_type, 
               a.cancelled,
               a.notes,
               a.room, 
               a.driver_id,
               b.id, 
               b.dep_symbol, 
               b.dep_location_id 
               FROM 
               general_reservations a
               INNER JOIN 
               routes b
               WHERE 
               a.cancelled<>'2' 
               AND a.date_trip BETWEEN '$find_begin' AND '$find_end' 
               AND b.dep_symbol LIKE '$code'
               AND b.id LIKE a.route_id 
               ORDER BY a.date_trip, b.dep_symbol, a.route_id";
```

Notice that I do have a.id and b.id from two different tables.

Comment: write a.id as AID likewise b.id as BID (ALIAS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [**alias**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html) name,

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id AS aid,
               a.route_id,                 
               a.requester,
               a.reservation,
               a.reservation_date,
               a.reservation_by, 
               a.telephone, 
               a.email, 
               a.firstname, 
               a.lastname, 
               a.qty_pax, 
               a.date_trip,
               a.time_trip, 
               a.trip_type, 
               a.cancelled,
               a.notes,
               a.room, 
               a.driver_id,
               b.id AS bid, 
               b.dep_symbol, 
               b.dep_location_id 
               FROM 
               general_reservations a
               INNER JOIN 
               routes b
               WHERE 
               a.cancelled<>'2' 
               AND a.date_trip BETWEEN '$find_begin' AND '$find_end' 
               AND b.dep_symbol LIKE '$code'
               AND b.id LIKE a.route_id 
               ORDER BY a.date_trip, b.dep_symbol, a.route_id";
```

Comment: Was my pleasure to accept your answer @Rikesh! Hope to see you around.